# Proof for the single variable case of the inverse function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble proving the inverse function theorem for real valued functions. I have seen a proof for the general case using the contraction mapping theorem, but I imagine it is much easier in this setting.

Let $f:(a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$, and suppose $f'(x_0)\neq 0$ for some $x_0\in (a, b)$, say $f'(x_0)>0$. Since $f'$ is continuous on $(a, b)$, then there exists some $\delta>0$ with $x_0\pm \delta\in (a, b)$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$, 
$$
|f'(x)-f'(x_0)|<f'(x_0).
$$
In other words, $f$ is strictly increasing on $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$. I want to show that $f^{-1}$ exists here and is differentiable, but I'm not sure where to go now.

My homework asks to construct an inverse and show that it is $C^1$.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing on $I$, it's a bijection from $I$ onto its image. That immediately defines $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I added a little more information. I need to explicitly construct $f^{-1}$ and show that it is differentiable on a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable in a nbd of $x_0$, then it has a linear approximation in that neighborhood. As long as the derivative is nonzero, that linear approximation is invertible, leading to another linear approximation. Hence, $f^{-1}$ is invertible.